# Как передать $_FILES через ajax?

Tags: ajax, php

Делаю загрузку аватара на сайт. Как передать в отдельный php массив $_FILES через javascript?

Comment: Никак - только если флэшем перегнать в двоичный вид и потом на сервере собрать обратно.

Comment: Да ладно никак :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и на старых браузерах без всяких доп.плагинов, хоть в ie6.
Обычная форма с полем выбора файла, при нажатии на субмит JavaScript создаёт невидимый iframe и добавляет форме аттрибут target="*имя_ифрейма*". Сервер принимает файл и возвращает в этот ифрейм некий JavaScript код, который вызывает некую заранее прописанную в основном окне (не в iframe) JavaScript-функцию, которая делает все изменения на странице, которые должны произойти после загрузки файла.
Ну и есть ещё swfuploader (кажется, так называется)

Answer (score 1):

1. Перед тем как задавать вопрос, воспользуйтесь поиском, такие вопросы уже подымались.
2. Продублирую свой ответ:

Не так давно на другом ресурсе спрашивали или такие возможно, поэтому делал [пример](http://sh.s.wap3.com.ua/ta/) мультиаплоад (несколько файлов за раз) на ajax

Думаю поможет. Естественно броузер должен поддерживать FileAPI

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.